# Scraping a webpage in python with a multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html

I need to get data from a table in this website https://www.cashbackforex.com/en-US/tools/economic-impacts.aspx using python.
The code that I wrote so far is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.cashbackforex.com/en-US/tools/economic-impacts.aspx'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36'}

    # parsing parameters
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    print(soup.select('input[type="button"]'))
    data = {
        'dnn$ctr1601$Chart$ddlCurrencies': 'USD',
        'dnn$ctr1601$Chart$ddlReports': 'US Change in NonFarm Payrolls',
        'dnn$ctr1601$Chart$ddlTimeZone': '(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time',
        '__EVENTTARGET': soup.find('input', {'name': '__EVENTTARGET'}).get('value', ''),
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': soup.find('input', {'name': '__EVENTARGUMENT'}).get('value', ''),
        '__VIEWSTATE': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'}).get('value', ''),
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'}).get('value', ''),
        'btnApplyTools': soup.find('input', {'id': 'btnApplyTools'}).get('value', '')
    }

    # parsing data
    response = session.post(url, data=data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    print(soup)
```

but every time I run the program I can't find the values in table. I think the program doesn't send the input values to server, but I'm not sure.

The following table:

[image]

Comment: What request are you trying to mimic? When I click the red "Apply" button I don't see a POST to `economic-impacts.aspx` in the browser developer tools..

Comment: When I change a variable, i.e. USD, US Change in Nonfarm Payroll and hit the apply bottom. The Table called "Event History" below it, changes.
I need to extract that table. But When I read that table with BeautifulSoup, non of those rows are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked provided page and found that there is no need in `Session()` and sending multiple parameters to get required table. All you need is to specify `inst` parameter (something like identifier of filter) and `timezone`. For example, for `USD`/`US Change in NonFarm Payrolls` `inst` parameter value is `10332295`, `timezone` for `(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time` is `3`.

So your request should be something like

```
params = {'inst': '10332295', 'timezone': '3'}
response = requests.get('https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/HistoricalEventFigures.ashx', params=params)
```

And then you can parse `response` in convenient way, e.g.:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml = minidom.parseString(response.text)
print([i.childNodes[0].wholeText for i in xml.getElementsByTagName("Date")])
print([i.childNodes[0].wholeText for i in xml.getElementsByTagName("ReportName")])
...
```

The output:

```
['2 Dec 2016', '4 Nov 2016', '7 Oct 2016', '2 Sep 2016', '5 Aug 2016', '8 Jul 2016', '3 Jun 2016',...]
['US Change in NonFarm Payrolls', 'US Change in NonFarm Payrolls', 'US Change in NonFarm Payrolls', 'US Change in NonFarm Payrolls',...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code partially works, But I need the program to go through all the dropdown lists. so i can get all of them. For example, it needs to start from AUD find all the events starting from AU Bank Holiday - ANZAC Day to the end.
How did you find the "https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/HistoricalEventFigures.ashx" ?

Comment: When you click `Apply` button, you send 3 `GET` requests: `https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/Candles.ashx` for data displayed on chart, `https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/SameTimeReports.ashx` for first table and `https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/HistoricalEventFigures.ashx`  for second (`Event History`) table.

Comment: Each pair of `Event finder` like `AUD`-`AU Bank Holiday - ANZAC` has its own `inst` parameter, but I don't know what exact range of `inst` values you should apply for `AUD` pairs as they seem to be not sequential...